# no_color in overridden django command does not work

Tags: django

I have overridden django `check` command in `~/<project_name>/commands/management/commands/check.py` looking like this:

```py
from django.core.management.commands import check
class Command(check.Command):
    help = 'My Customized Version of the Original check Command'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('>>> Running customized check')

        options['deploy'] = True
        options['no_color'] = True

        super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
```

Running `manage.py check 2>/tmp/check-output` triggers the command, but the problem here is in spite of setting 'no_color', the output is still colored and I have to run it as `manage.py check --no-color 2>/tmp/check-output`

Comment: `no_color` is not a parameter that is passed to the management command itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`no_color` is not a parameter that is passed to the management command itself, but when the `BaseCommand` is constructed, so you work with:

```
from django.core.management.commands import check


class Command(check.Command):
    help = 'My Customized Version of the Original check Command'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['no_color'] = not kwargs.get('force_color', False)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('>>> Running customized check')

        options['deploy'] = True

        super().handle(*args, **options)
```

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.